# Separate Real Words from Random Strings

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I'm storing a list of keywords that have been used throughout all searches on a site, and I'm getting a lot of random strings in the keywords field. Here's a sample of the data that I'm getting back:

```
fRNPRXiPtjDrfTDKH
boom
Mule deer
gVXOFEzRWi
cbFXZcCoSiKcmrvs
Owner Financed ,owner Financed
```

I'm trying to find a way in SQL or ColdFusion to figure out if something has valid English words, or if it's a random set of characters. I've tried doing some digging for n-gram analysis, but can't seem to come up with any useful solutions that I can run directly on my servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: The code is now on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ybanrab/s6Bs5/1/ it may be interesting to copy and paste a page of news copy and paste in your test data

I'd suggest trying to analyse the probabilities of the individual characters following each other. Below is an example in JavaScript I've written but that ought to translate to T-SQL or ColdFusion pretty easily.

The idea is that you feed in good phrases (the corpus) and analyse the frequency of letters following other letters. If you feed it "this thin the" you'll get something like this:

```
{
 t:{h:3},
 h:{i:2,e:1},
 i:{s:1,n:1},
 s:{},
 n:{}
}
```

You'll get most accuracy by feeding in hand-picked known good inputs from the data you're analysing, but you may also get good results by feeding in plain english. In the example below I'm computing this, but you can obviously store this once you're happy with it.

You then run the sample string against the probabilities to give it a score. This version ignores case, word starting letter, length etc, but you could use them as well if you want. 
 You then just need to decide on a threshold score and filter like that.

I'm fairly sure this kind of analysis has a name, but my google-fu is weak today.
You can paste the code below into a script block to get an idea of how well (or not) it works.

```
var corpus=["boom","Mule Deer", "Owner Financed ,owner Financed", "This is a valid String","The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"];

var probs={};
var previous=undefined;

//Compute the probability of one letter following another
corpus.forEach(function(phrase){
    phrase.split(" ").forEach(function(word){
        word.toLowerCase().split("").forEach(function(chr){
            //set up an entry in the probabilities table
            if(!probs[chr]){
                probs[chr]={};
            }
            //If this isn't the first letter in the word, record this letter as following the previous one
            if(previous){
                if(!probs[previous][chr]){
                    probs[previous][chr]=0; 
                }
                probs[previous][chr]++;
            }
            //keep track of the previous character
            previous=chr;

        });
        //reset previous as we're moving onto a different word
        previous=undefined;
    })
});


function calculateProbability(suspect){
    var score=0;
    var previous=undefined;
    suspect.toLowerCase().split("").forEach(function(chr){
        if(previous && probs[previous] && probs[previous][chr]){
            //Add the score if there is one, otherwise zero
            score+=probs[previous][chr];
        }
        previous=chr;
    });
    return score/suspect.length;
}

console.log(calculateProbability("boom"));
console.log(calculateProbability("Mood"));
console.log(calculateProbability("Broom"));
console.log(calculateProbability("sajkdkas dak"));
```

Comment: This solution definitely gives me something to think about. I'll do some experimentation, and if this ends up working, I'll be sure to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've updates the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ybanrab/39E5c/ this one attempts to correct for the number of words sampled to give more consistent scores. It seems to work reasonably enough I think. Thanks for posting the question, it's been a really interesting problem to attack

Comment: You're doing character n-gram modelling, with one exception: your calculateProbability method should multiply probabilities, not sum them. You'll probably underflow doing this, so you can sum the logs instead, and then normalise by the word length. As opposed to a word-based analysis, this will allow you to find word-like strings that haven't been seen as words, at the expense of being tricked by strings that are only non-word-like outside the Markov horizon.

Comment: Thanks very much Ben for putting a name to what I was attempting to do. I'll take a look at multiplying the probabilities together to see what kind of numbers I get out.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to check your words against frequency lists: dictionaries won't work because they don't contain grammatical inflections, proper nouns, compounds, and a whole load of other stuff that's valid.

The problem with naive checking against n-gram data is there is a lot of noise in the lower frequency words. The easiest thing to do which should give you the correct answer in the overwhelming majority of cases is to truncate a list of frequency counted words from somewhere suitably large (Google n-gram, Wikipedia, etc) at the top 50,000 or 100,000 words. Adjust the threshold as appropriate to get the results you're looking for, but then you can just check if any/all of your query terms appear in this list.

If you want to know if the query is grammatical, or sensible as a unit rather than its constituent parts, that's a whole other question of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are some non-dictionary-words that can be valid searches (e.g. `gethostbyname` is a valid and meaningful search here on SO, but not a dictionary word). On the other hand, there are dictionary words that have absolutely nothing to do with your website.

Instead of trying to guess what is a word and what isn't, you could simply check if the search query produced a non-empty result. Those with empty results must be complete off-topic or gibberish.

Comment: Potentially, but we want to keep the non-zero results so that we know who's searching for what. Just because I don't have something someone wants, doesn't mean it isn't a valid search :). And this particular site won't have any nonsense words, since it has a very narrow focus.

Comment: The only reliable way to check if something is an English word or not is to look it up in a dictionary. You need a searchable English dictionary of some form to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a

[Bayesian Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering)